# Why does any transitive model satisfy extensionality?

Tags: set-theory, axioms

I see it stated as something very clear, but i can't figure it out.
i found a [proof in Jech](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=pLxq0myANiEC&pg=PA83&lpg=PA83&dq=transitive%20model%20satisfies%20extensionality&source=bl&ots=0Dg9JBuW5G&sig=P3DduFR6LWQuP2CB9wS2duYJQhA&hl=iw&sa=X&ei=UeopUd3yE42RswaumoHYDg&ved=0CGoQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=transitive%20model%20satisfies%20extensionality&f=false)(old version) which goes through the concept of restricted formulas, which i don't quite understand. (i'm not sure i understand the notation in his Lemma 10.1, the statement numbered 10.5)
Is there a way to show it directly?

Comment: ok, i edited, thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\mathbf{M}$ be transitive, and suppose $x , y \in \mathbf{M}$ are distinct.  Then, by extensionality in $V$, there must be (in $V$) a $u$ which belongs to either $x \setminus y$ or $y \setminus x$.  In either case the transitivity of $\mathbf{M}$ implies that $u \in \mathbf{M}$, and so $\mathbf{M} \models \neg ( u \in x \leftrightarrow u \in y )$, or, more meaningfully $\mathbf{M} \models \neg ( \forall u ) ( u \in x \leftrightarrow u \in y )$.  Therefore $$\mathbf{M} \models ( \forall x ) ( \forall y ) ( x \neq y \rightarrow \neg ( \forall u ) ( u \in x \leftrightarrow u \in y ))$$ which (logically equivalent to) the Axiom of Extensionality in Jech's text.

Comment: I'm confused, doesn't the statement " there must be a u which belongs to either x∖y or y∖x" rely on the Axiom of Extentionality? When you say that if x and y are distinct then there is an element which is in one but not in the second, you're assuming that they are distinguished by their elements, which is what the axiom say...

Comment: @UrBen-Ari-Tishler: Yes and no.  The axioms of set theory are meant to reflect our intuitive notions about what sets are and what we can do with them.  Perhaps the most basic intuitive notion about sets is that a set is completely determined by its elements, which is a non-technical way of expressing Extensionality.  So really the Axiom of Extensionality is a description of the Universe of Sets (non-Platonism be damned!).  [cont...]

Comment: [...inued]  Note, also, that even the Lemma that you link to suggests that some assumption needs to be made: If $\mathbf M$ is a transitive class and $\varphi$ a restricted formula, then for all $x_1 , \ldots , x_n \in \mathbf M$, $\mathbf M \models \varphi (x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ iff $\varphi(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$.  Thus, if $X , Y$ are distinct sets with the same elements and $\mathbf M$ is a transitive class containing both of them, then $\mathbf M$ cannot satisfy Extensionality.

Comment: it seems that in this case there's not much meaning to provide a "proof", if we define the transitive model based on this axiom, it's sort of embeded in it

Comment: @UrBen-Ari-Tishler: Well, you have to start somewhere.  But note that we can look at this all purely formally, and note that the class $\mathbf M$ is really hiding a formula $\varphi (x,p)$ of the language of set theory, and saying "$\mathbf M$ satisfies the Axiom of Extensionality" is just a more natural way of saying that "the relativization of the Axiom of Extensionality to $\mathbf M$" is a theorem of ZFC."

Comment: @UrYa'ar, Of my understanding, "x = y" is defined as "\mathbf{M} \models ( \forall x ) ( \forall y ) ( x \neq y \rightarrow \neg ( \forall u ) ( u \in x \leftrightarrow u \in y ))". So what we need is to ensure that this still holds when relativized to M. Please correct me if wrong.

Comment: First of all, revisiting this, I now understand where my confusion in the first comment comes from. It should be noted that the statement "there must be $u$ which belongs to either $x∖y$ or $y∖x$" is a statement in the "ambient world of sets, $V$", which we do assume that satisfies extensionality, and then we use transitivity to deduce that this $u$ is in $M$ and achieve a contradiction.

Comment: Second, @AnduinWilde, $x=y$ is not _defined_ in that way - equivalence is a primitive notion, stating that $x,y$ simply denote the same element. In the context of set theory we want to have extensionality - that the = relation is characterized using the $\in$ relation. What needs to be shown is that the model $M$ also "knows" that this characterization holds.

Comment: @Ur Ya'ar If I remember correctly, in early history of set theory/zfc, "=" is not a primitive notion, but defined as ... So that is why the extensionality is a iff (and if you treat = as primitive, stating that x and y denoting the same element, then just a -> is enough)

Comment: @AnduinWilde Well I admit I don't know what were the convensions in the early history of ZFC. Currently, in the two main textbooks of set theory (Kunen and Jech) the axiom of extensionality is indeed stated with only one direction and not with iff.

Answer (score 4):

The $\in$-relation of transitive models is the true $\in$ of the universe, and we know that the universe satisfies extensionality.

Now suppose $M$ is a transitive model, and that $x,y\in M$. By transitivity we know that $x,y\subseteq M$ as well. Therefore $M$ knows all of their elements. If $x\neq y$ then without loss of generality there is some $z\in x\setminus y$, but $M$ knows about $z$ and since $M$ agrees with the universe about $\in$, $M$ also knows that $z\in x\setminus y$.

So whenever $M$ is transitive and $x,y\in M$ are distinct elements, $M\models x\neq y$.